# Link width on div with background image

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="url here">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Name</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {
width: 20%;
}
.logo {
background: url(images/ui-sprite.svg) no-repeat 0 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
margin: 25px 0;
}
```

The issue I have is with linking the logo (background image). At the moment the link area you can hover over is the full width of the container div, despite the fact that the logo class has a defined width. Any ideas here on best practice with linking of background images?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you're doing, but it seems to be something what's not shared in your question, see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/0tc976a4/

Comment: Hi there. It is there. Notice how the red background is also a clickable link, whereas I only want the background image of .logo to be the link. Cheers.
http://jsfiddle.net/0tc976a4/1/

Comment: Moving the link inside of the logo container seems to have the desired effect. Not sure why though! http://jsfiddle.net/0tc976a4/3/

Comment: it was my first thought: it's because you set the width of the child element... if you set the parent, then you'll have the desired effect...

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be ultimately useful, and less markup too!

http://ran.ge/2012/04/03/css-trick-turning-a-background-image-into-a-clickable-link-take-2/